# How can I turn a custom wordpress page into a product page?

Tags: plugin-development, customization, permalinks, templates

I want to create a custom wordpress template product page using PHP.
I don't want to override the default product page, but I want to register
my custom template page as a product page.
I have created a PHP template page that after doing some processing comes up with a list of product IDs that it wants to display (this processing doesn't have to do with wordpress so I don't use WP_Query to retrieve those IDs). Then, I am using the woocommerce [product] shortcode to display those IDs.
The probelm is that if I save this page with a slug of `www.website.com/my-custom-page`, then the URL `www.website.com/my-custom-page` works, but the url `www.website.com/my-custom-page/?post_type=product` yields error 404. The reason I want the second URL to work is because my filters only work when the URL parameter `post_type=product` is present.

So, does anybody know how I can register my page (or my template) as a wordpress product page? So that the second URL does not give error 404?